# How set more "jwt" AuthGuard in nestjs?

Tags: jwt, passport.js, nestjs, passport-jwt

i'm new to nestjs, i've already set a "jwt" PassportStrategy with his relative AuthGuard, now i have to create a complete different "jwt" PassportStrategy and his relative AuthGuard, how can i do this? Do you have any examples?

Answer (score 5):

Firstly you create another strategy class.
The second argument when extending the base PassportStrategy will be the name of your strategy which you can use with AuthGuard to specify which
strategy it will use.

```
export class OtherStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'other-strategy')
{ STRATEGY IMPLEMENTATION }
```

Then you can use it in your controller like

```
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('other-strategy')
@Post('/my-endpoint')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm testing this solution, but it gives me this error: "Unknown authentication strategy "jwt-temporary" any advice?

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention that you should register the strategy as a provider in modules where necessary, and again make sure you use the same name when extending PassportStrategy and when using it with AuthGuard.

Answer (score 0):

Have you provided the jwt strategy in the auth module providers array?

Here is a sample file: auth.module.ts:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    UsersModule,
    PassportModule,
    JwtModule.register({
      privateKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '60s' },
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService, LocalStrategy, JwtStrategy],
})
export class AuthModule { }
```